# Does Google Maps in android app works in UK

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have created android application that uses Google Maps, ans it works fine here in Palestine(Middle east). When someone try it on UK either on the emulator or on the real device it doesn't show any map!

What is the possible problem ?

Comment: Have you checked logcat for errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UK tester doesn't have an Internet connection, or is using a different APK than the one you tested (and therefore you might have a problem with your signing key and Maps API key), or is testing using a device that does not legitimately have Google Maps on it, or something along those lines.

Comment: Yes the problem was in the Map key !